# QT debugger displaying incorrect value for variable (false instead of true)

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using QT Creator 3.5.1. I have QT 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit). Revision e548635a24. I also have Debugging Tools for Windows/CDB installed and auto detected by QT Creator.

While debugging I encountered this situation:

[image: madness]

Notice that isUdp is shown as being false, even though the current line arrow shows that we entered the true portion of the if statement.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may have declared the same variable (isUdp) both as member and local variable.
Try using a different name for your variable. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not the problem in my case. I checked my code to be sure, but even that wasn't necessary since the popup indicating the false value shows when you hover over the isUdp variable inside the if statement.